# How can parse multiple tag with same name iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have xml http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=20070458&u=c how can i parse from tag  **(which is twice or may be more) attribute day and more** ...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an NSMutableArray and add object when you found the element name same as required in in the method `didEndElement` method

**edited**

Add this code in `didStartElement:` method

```
if([elementname isEqualToString:@"yweather"]){
   [yourmutableArray addObject:attributeDict]
}
```

Comment: But here didEndElement not possible due to not closing tag just like <tag>......</tag> here situation like <yweather:forecast day="Thu" date="12 Jul 2012" low="27" high="34" text="Thunderstorms" code="4"/>
<yweather:forecast day="Fri" date="13 Jul 2012" low="27" high="34" text="Thunderstorms" code="4"/>

Comment: I do this but the problem is ,when second time <yweather:forecast tag is found and we parse day .... etc So how can I differentiate among these day or etc attribute ......

Comment: You will differentiate by the index of the mutableArray. 1st index represent the first tag item, 2nd represent the 2nd one and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Are you new to iphone programming, check out some tutorials for xml parsing and other..

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

this is a sample application which uses GDataXML parser..

http://db.tt/qoERN0LB